# Какую информацию о компьютере можно собрать использую python?

Tags: python

Хотелось бы узнать серийник ЖД или модель материнки , IP , резолюшн мб

Comment: Может задействовать операционную систему?

Comment: Любую, которую позволяет собрать операционная система

Answer (score 2):

С помощью `subprocess.run(...)` можно вызывать внешние программы. Соответственно, если скрипт запущен с нужными правами, то можно узнать всё то же, что предоставляет API вашей ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно использовать модуль **platform**

[Документация](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-platform-python/#platform.node)